# Processing time applying dask_geopandas. Dissolve a polygon layer with parallelization

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, parallel-processing, parallel

I'm testing the dask_geopandas library to dissolve a polygon layer. However, at the moment the processing time applying the dissolution without parallelization (df) is lower than applying the supposed parallelization algorithm with the dask_geopandas library (ddf).

What could be the reason?

Is there any option to parallelise a dissolve?

Code:

```py
import geopandas
import dask_geopandas
import time

%%time
df = geopandas.read_file(r'D:\GIS4tech\201216_ACH_Venezuela\2_ACTIVIDADES\PT1_ESTIMACION\PT1_A08_P05_BBDD_agroclimatica\GIS\01_Identificacion_Parcelas\Metodo_STD_S1\Parcelas_prev\reclass_S1_MUN_4.shp')
df = df.explode()
df.head

%%time
dissolved = df.dissolve("Dis")
dissolved

%%time
dissolved_ddf = ddf.dissolve("Dis")
dissolved_ddf = dissolved_ddf.compute()
dissolved_ddf

%%time
dissolved_ddf_2 = ddf.dissolve("Dis", split_out=4)
dissolved_ddf_2 = dissolved_ddf_2.compute()
dissolved_ddf_2
```

Times:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check if it is utilizing all available CPU's when you run dissolve using dask ?

Comment: Yes, at the start of execution a large part of the CPU is used, but then it drops back to ~8%.

Comment: I mean do you see all CPUs being utilized or just one CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I am the developer of [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

The library [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) speeds up spatial operations on larger datasets by using eg. parallel processing. It also has a [geofileops.dissolve](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.dissolve.html#geofileops.dissolve) function.

Sample code snippet:

```
import geofileops as gfo

input_path = r'D:\GIS4tech\201216_ACH_Venezuela\2_ACTIVIDADES\PT1_ESTIMACION\PT1_A08_P05_BBDD_agroclimatica\GIS\01_Identificacion_Parcelas\Metodo_STD_S1\Parcelas_prev\reclass_S1_MUN_4.shp'
output_path = r'D:\temp\output.gpkg'
gfo.dissolve(
    input_path=input_path,
    output_path=output_path,
    explodecollections=False,
)
```